# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, нужна ли здесь запятая:

Традиционно для многих стран(,) в Италии пик туристического сезона приходится на лето.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Традиционно для многих стран,**  пик туристического сезона в Италии приходится на лето.

**Оборот (со значением соответствия)  можно обособить**, но при этом надо изменить порядок слов так,  чтобы предложение  имело структуру СПП  **с придаточным в его начале** по образцу: В соответствии с традицией многих стран, пик туристического сезона в Италии приходится на лето.

**Примеры обособления оборота в середине предложения:**

Правда, сначала, **традиционно для всех киевских мальчишек**, был футбол: прыгучего и уже тогда высокого мальчишку определили на ворота. [Наталья Быканова. Лидер выходит из тени // «Огонек». № 10, 1991]

Зато ― **опять же традиционно для «французов**» ― коробка немного разочаровывает своими длинными передачами. [Валерий Чусов. В гольф на деньги (2002) // «Автопилот», 2002.06.15]

Когда со временем у него поселилась и его мать, и с Мариной они ― **традиционно для всех веков** ― не слишком ладили, жизнь для него сделалась просто невыносимой. [Наталия Басовская, Г. Бельская. «И все-таки она вертится...» // «Знание - сила», 2008]

Answer (score 1):

Предложение требует правки. Как вариант:

**В Италии, как и во многих странах, пик туристического сезона приходится на лето.**

---

Дополнение по поводу употребления слов "традиционно для"

Схематически представим наше предложение  в виде

*Традиционно для множества М, элемент х <свойство или действие>.*

Это предложение можно считать корректным, только если х принадлежит множеству М.

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

*Первое отделение, где заведующим был доктор Калембет, традиционно для Колымы пеллогрозно-дизентерийное, считалось инфекционным, состояло из нескольких палаток, то росло, то уменьшалось. [Варлам Шаламов. О Колыме (1970-1979)]*

Первое отделение, о котором идет речь, находится на Калыме, поэтому предложение построено корректно.

А вот предложение из вопроса - неудачное, потому что только с большой натяжкой можно считать это есть такое множество - "многие страны", для которого характерно то, что "пик туристического сезона приходится на лето", и совсем не очевидно из контекста, что Италия принадлежит этому множеству. Если заменить "многие страны" на "европейские страны", то все становится на свои места:

**Традиционно для европейских стран, пик туристического сезона в Италии приходится на лето.**

Answer (score 0):

Нестройная и слабая по информативности (всё лето пик?) фраза, требующая правки по содержанию и форме.

Если сохранить это содержание: «*Традиционный для многих стран пик туристического сезона в Италии приходится на лето*». А лучше: «*Традиционный для многих стран пик туристического сезона в Италии приходится {на начало} лета*» или «Традиционно для многих стран, как и Италии, пик туристического сезона приходится на... лето.»